# show all columns in a column group even when filter reurns 0 rows

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

lets say i have a table with the following format

```
Empmanager   Billable status(Billable, non billable, partial)   month
ali           billable                                            aug
ali           billable                                            aug
sana          non billable                                        aug
```

lets say i need a report manager wise and month wise
  in case i need a report filtered on sana as emp manager and billable as billable status
i get a report like this

```
empmanager 
sana
```

and in case i need a report filtered on ali as emp manager and billable as billable status
i get a report like this

```
empmanager  billablestatus
ali          2
```

the column billable status does not get displayed in case of sana because there is no data for billable employees for sana.

**i need to generate report where columns inside column group gets displayed even when the data returned forthem is nothing.**
i hope i made myself clear.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.
1) There will be another table where your Employee's and their statuses are stored. Use outer Join to the managers and this table you have shown. And in the query pick the Manager name from the main table.

2) This one is bit like cutting the corners. Instead of having it under the column name you can have the group header which will display the Parameter you have passed.

Comment: Thanks Bhupendra. hat is one work around but i cannot pass parameters in here.i have to keep my report as onise as option free as i can.